# Conflig between netty-transport-native-epoll and netty-tcnative-boringssl-static

Tags: netty, epoll, grpc-java, boringssl

I am doing service as connector using `grpc 1.13.1` with the following roles:
- Handle requests from apps (as server side)
- Categorize requests, after that forwarding through other services (as client side).

Between the connector that calls the other services through the domain gateway, nginx uses ssl

The problem encountered conflict when:

- Server side uses lib:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId> io.netty </ groupId>
      <artifactId> netty-transport-native-epoll </ artifactId>
      <version> 4.1.17.Final </ version>
      <classifier> linux-x86_64 </ classifier>
  </ dependency>
  ```
- Client side uses ssl lib

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId> io.netty </ groupId>
      <artifactId> netty-tcnative-boringssl-static </ artifactId>
      <version> 2.0.7.Final </ version>
  </ dependency>
  ```

and the error is

> code = UNAVAILABLE ', description = Channel closed while performing the negotiation protocol

How do I fix the error described above?